# Национальность "чукча"

Tags: этикет

Читал недавно книгу о Чукотке, и там автор всячески избегал слова "чукча", называя местное население и родным термином (сейчас не вспомню - уж больше труднопроизносим), и просто "тундровые люди".
А насколько вообще название национальности "чукча" грамотное и, если хотите, политкорректное (в хорошем смысле этого слова)?

Answer (score 1):

Мне попадалась старая статья советских времён, где обсуждался многонациональный состав литераторов. Там в перечислении упоминался "... чукча [Юрий] Рытхэу", так что это политкорректно. Это обычное русское наименование, которое вполне может не совпадать с самоназванием народности. Понятно, что ввиду распространения анекдотов "про чукчу", где чукча - синоним живущего вдали от цивилизации, сами представители народности со временем стали неохотно так себя называть.